# How to display current time in a specific format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I just want to display the current month and year in the format like Jan13, which means January 2013. By the way, it should be the local time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple. See the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) documentation.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%b%y")
'Jan13'
```